# Why Is The Row Height Of These Two Tables Different?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Please have a look at the simulator screen shot below wherein you will see:

1. A horizontal stack view with three buttons
2. A table view with a red header, a brown footer and a light grey background
3. A horizontal stack view with three buttons
4. A table view with a cyan header, an orange footer and a light dark background

I created that interface via a storyboard. In interface builder I was careful to create both of the tables in exactly the same way, with the exception of the colors.
I have included an Xcode screen shot that might be helpful. Notice that the labels added to the prototype cells have their edges pinned to the cell's edges.

Nowhere am I taking any action to set the table row heights. In the datasource's cellForRowAt method I am printing the cell heights: they are reported to be 44, which I understand is the default.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell: UITableViewCell

    if tableView === upperTable {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "upper")!
        (cell as! TableViewCell).label.text = upperData[indexPath.row]
        print("Upper table cell height = \(cell.bounds.height)")
    }
    else {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "lower")!
        (cell as! TableViewCell).label.text = lowerData[indexPath.row]
        print("Lower table cell height = \(cell.bounds.height)")
    }

    return cell
}
```

Can anyone suggest a possible reason for the final row heights of the two tables being different?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Constraints looks different for the label in both tableView cells

Comment: Thx Satish. That was it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In one table, the one with the pink header it looks like, your constraints set the content view's *bottom edge* to match the bottom of the label (so you are moving the bottom edge of the content view to the bottom of the label making the content view's height dependent on the label's height).

In the other you are setting the content view's *bottom margin* to match the label's bottom (so you are are moving the margin to correspond to the label's bottom, not the bottom **edge** of the view).

Comment: Scott, Thk u so much for your eagle eyes!